# When using the forward command is the movement specified carried out after each tick?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make turtles move along fixed paths that the user can draw in the u.i. The forward command can make turtles move a certain fraction of a patch forward per tick I assume, however to instigate smooth movement would it be possible to specify a fixed movement per tick in the setup commands for turtles? If this is possible what would be the basic structuring of the code I would use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fd command (bk as well) accept floating-point inputs. I.e.

```
 Ask turtles [ fd .01 ]
```

Makes each turtle move forward 1/100th of a patch. This movement happens at the time of the command.

Tick does not have any connection to when commands are carried out. If you set view updates to on ticks it can effect when you see updates otherwise it is usually a scheme for keeping track of how many times go has run.

A sample model of turtles moving at different speeds.

```
Turtles-own [speed]
To setup
     Crt 100[
                  Set speed random-float 1
                  ]
 End

 To go
     Ask turtles[ rt 1 fd speed]
  End
```

Copy and paste that into a new model make setup and go buttons. Mess with it for a while.

Comment: so how could I make a turtle move at a fixed velocity as I cannot use the method I have described above?

Comment: I will put some sample code at the end of my answer.

Comment: Click the arrow get me some points ;) but really if you should select the best answers for your questions.

Comment: when you use crt the turtles are created at 0,0. Would it be possible to create the turtles on a patch with a certain colour for example?

Comment: Yes, "ask patch 6 7 [set color red]"

Comment: no sorry I meant is it possible to be able to make crt spawn on a certain patch colour?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64267/discussion-between-king-ink-and-akarr).